# Get all children users from parent id

Tags: mysql

I am working on php mlm base project and I am not able to get back all children users. I am passing parent_id as sponser id

```
select * from user where sponserid in(select id from users where sponserid = 1) or sponscerid = 1;

+----+--------+------------+
| id | name   | sponscorid |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 | one    |      NULL  |
|  2 | two    |         1  |
|  3 | three  |         1  |
|  4 | four   |         2  |
|  5 | five   |         2  |
|  6 | six    |         2  |
|  7 | seven  |         2  |
|  8 | eight  |         3  |
|  9 | nine   |         3  |
| 10 | ten    |         3  |
| 11 | eleven |         3  |
+----+--------+------------+
```

I  am using following query:

```
select * from user where sponserid in(select id from users where sponserid = 1) or sponscerid = 1;
```

But I only get children and grandchildren user up to 2 levels (that means I only get user whose sponscorid = 1 & 2 ). But i need all the children and grandchildren users for Parent User.

Comment: Where is the PHP? Maybe want to add in SQL tag.

Comment: Perhaps that's all that you want.